# Which characters are allowed in a VS project name?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know which characters are allowed in a VS project name? Is there a reference somewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> - Cannot contain any of the following characters: / ? : & \ * " < > | # %
> - Cannot contain unicode characters
> - Cannot contain surrogate characters
> - Cannot be reserved names including 'CON', 'AUX', 'PRN', 'COM1' or 'LPT2'
> - Cannot be '.' or '..'

I obtained this information by trying to create a project with a character I knew would not be accepted.  I.e. a character that is not allowed in NTFS file paths.  I.e. I used a project with the name | to get the error.

Comment: +1 Also some characters may be allowed in the project name but may also break when the CLR tries to load an assembly with those characters.  It is important to change the assembly name from the project name if your project name is not valid as an assembly name.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio returns the following error on trying to create a project with invalid characters:

[image: Invalid project name error in Visual Studio 2012]

> #### Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> ---
>
> New Project
>
> Project and solution names cannot:
>
> - contain any of the following characters: `/` `?` `:` `&` `\` `*` `"` `<` `>` `|` `#` `%`
> - contain Unicode control characters
> - contain surrogate characters
> - be system reserved names, including `CON`, `AUX`, `PRN`, `COM1` or `LPT2`
> - be `.` or `..`
>
> Please enter a valid name.
>
> ---
>
> <kbd>OK</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good idea to not use spaces or any other character which may be html-encoded. See http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/10/metadata-file-could-not-be-found-in.html